# react okta login - detect new login and call a rest api

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, okta

I'm trying to trap a fresh event of okta's LoginCallback component so that when a user newly logs in, I can make a rest call to update the user info in my database.

I created a custom LoginCallback to do this, but authState is always null when the useEffect is called.  I don't know why or where else to handle this event.  It seems like it's too early to try to access this authState to be able to get my access token.  I also want to do this only once, so putting this in the / (Home.js) might be the solution, but seems like more calls will happen than needed if I'm only relying on isAuthenticated to be true.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useOktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-react';
import { LoginCallback } from '@okta/okta-react';

const UpdateUserLoginCallback = () => {
  const { authState, oktaAuth } = useOktaAuth();

  const callApi = async () => {
    const name = authState.idToken.claims.name;
    // fetch access token
    const accessToken = authState.accessToken;

    // use access token to call your REST API
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/update', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ name: name }),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (authState?.isAuthenticated) {
      callApi();
    }
  }, [authState?.isAuthenticated]); // The effect depends on authState.isAuthenticated

  return <LoginCallback/>;
};

export default UpdateUserLoginCallback;
```

of course, I am using this custom component in my path for okta's /login/callback:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Security oktaAuth={oktaAuth} restoreOriginalUri={this.restoreOriginalUri}>
      <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/login/callback" component={UpdateUserLoginCallback}/>
      <SecureRoute path="/profile" component={Profile}/>
    </Security>
  );
}
```